# Querys pararam de funcionar

Tags: php, mysql, query, mysqli

Recentemente fiz uma alteração na tabela e após isso `SELECT` e `INSERT INTO` pararam de funcionar.

A principio o `INSERT INTO` não conseguia incluir dados na ultima coluna que inclui (centid), retornava `column 'centid' cannot be null`, porém o valor estava sendo passado (para resolver isso por enquanto passei a deixar essa coluna aceitar `NULL` e faço o `UPDATE` logo em seguida).

Além desse problema com o INSERT, um simples SELECT nessa tabela parou de funcionar através do PHP.

Em todos os casos eu verifiquei se haviam variáveis vazias e em todos os casos nada esta deixando de ser passado, inclusive no código a baixo, a variavel `$viagemid` esta passando o valor.

PHP:

```
$despesas = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `despesas` WHERE `viagemid` = '".$viagemid."'";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
$count_desp = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

    array_push($despesas, $row);
}
```

Nesse código especificamente, habilitei `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);` e o retorno foi:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'No index used in query/prepared statement SELECT * FROM `despesas` WHERE `viagemid` = ' 1041 '' in C:\Users\fchagas\Documents\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\editar_viagem.php:146 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\fchagas\Documents\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\editar_viagem.php(146): mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\fchagas\Documents\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\editar_viagem.php on line 146

O log do Apache (pode ser util):

`127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2017:21:18:39 -0300] "POST /nova_viagem.php HTTP/1.1" 200 19992
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2017:21:18:49 -0300] "GET /eds-modules/phpmyadmin4551x170208222435/sql.php?server=1&db=database&table=despesas&pos=0&token=dad73b6308c6b0dd8911a2c3312bf46e&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&_nocache=1487722729000434776 HTTP/1.1" 200 7204
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2017:21:18:49 -0300] "GET /eds-modules/phpmyadmin4551x170208222435/index.php?ajax_request=1&recent_table=1&token=dad73b6308c6b0dd8911a2c3312bf46e&no_debug=true&_nocache=1487722729416685739 HTTP/1.1" 200 1567
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2017:21:18:54 -0300] "GET /listar_viagem.php HTTP/1.1" 200 60541`

Comment: Peço 2 favores. Execute o comando SHOW CREATE TABLE `despesas` e posta aqui. Coloca também a SQL do INSERT que está dando erro. Essas duas informações, às vezes, pro si só são suficientes para identificar o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é um erro é apenas um aviso dizendo que a sua consulta poderia ser melhor executado. A causa é o `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL` que reporta além de erros warnings, avisos de perforce.

Esse aviso gerou uma exception e tirou o código do fluxo normal. Para pegar somente os erros use: `MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR` ou `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT|MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR` na chamada de `mysqli_report()`.

Comment: Obrigado, me expressei mal. Ele realmente não dá erro, e isso que esta dificultando minha vida.

Comment: @FelipeChagas veja se assim retorna algum erro: `$query = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);`

Comment: Não retornou errou. O código segue como se o resultado estivesse correto, porém a mesma query direto no console retorna o resultado correto.

Comment: @FelipeChagas olhou o log do apache no servidor de produção?

Comment: Nunca mexi nesse log, então não sei o que estou procurando, mas vou colocar na pergunta as ultimas linhas do log que foram gravadas durante o meu ultimo teste.